# Symfony2 deployment: got MappingException: Class "xxx" is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I know this issue has been asked here a LOT of times and I have read at least ten of the posts here... but I don't seem to quite understand what to do, so I ask for your advice and consideration given that this is my first symfony deployment and in fact my first site deployment. So many thanks in advance for this.

This is my road map

1- I have made a site that works fine on localhost. Its super simple and it uses entities created via .yml files and generate entities command of doctrine. I also used the generate crud to modify those entities so there is quite few code of myself in that.

2- I copied all the project files into a ftp server and as far as I understand the site is online because I can access to config.php for example

3- I created a database on the server, created the tables via sql (which was dump via doctrine:schema:craeate --dump-sql), created a user to have all privileges.

4- I updated the parameters.yml file to reflect the new database info

3- Whenever I try to run the app I got this error of not valid entity or mapped superclass.

Additional notes:

I've already made this three things in order to solve it but I've got the same error all the time

1: copied this two lines in my app.php file on the server under the "uses" lines.

```
ini_set('eaccelerator.enable', 0);
ini_set('eaccelerator.optimizer', 0);
```

this was to try to disable the eaccelerator...but indeed I don't know if this is running on the server tough.

2: modify the setup.php file under /mysite/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools

```
    public static function createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array $paths, $isDevMode = false, $proxyDir = null, Cache $cache = null, $useSimpleAnnotationReader = true)
    {
       $config = self::createConfiguration($isDevMode, $proxyDir, $cache);
       $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver($paths, false));

       return $config;
   }
```

This was because I have read on others answers that that setting false on the second argument will help to solve it... but the fact is that I do not know if this is the correct place for  doing so.

3: I check the main config.yml file for this line and it was already there:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_mapping: true
```

Finally, if it is maybe important to point out, when I run the config.php I get this two mayor problems:

> Major problems have been detected and must be fixed before continuing:
>
> Set detect_unicode to off in php.ini*.
>
> Add "phar" to suhosin.executor.include.whitelist in php.ini*.

Please if someone can check this out and help my solve it I would be immensely thankful. I am really counting on you because I do not have other to ask. Keep my fingers crossed.

Comment: Have you fixed the *Major problems*?

Comment: not yet my friend, since I cant access the php.ini... I think for that I will need to wait until tomorrow to try to call with some support person of the server on a labour hour. 
But do you think that those problems could be causing the former error from doctrine?

Comment: I don't know, but since Symfony2 detect them as *major problems* I think you should try to fix them.

Comment: Did the `doctrine:schema:create` actually work as expected? Are you getting this with all entity classes, or a specific one?